# how to save multiple data in a 1 table row

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to create a payment integration using paypal on my site and after i send  multiple of item using cart to paypal and when paypal return back the item how to save it to my database

this is how i request payment from paypal

```
foreach($paypal_product['items'] as $key=>$p_item)
    {       
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($p_item['itm_qty']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_price']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_name']);
        $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_code']);
}
```

This is what paypal return back to me

```
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Android%20Phone%20FX1
[L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Television%20DXT
```

this is what i'm using and its not saving the data

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}       
foreach($httpParsedResponseAr as $key=>$p_item){
    $itemname='';
    $itemqty='';
    $itemnumber='';

    if(substr($key,0,5)=='L_NAME'){
        $itemname=$p_item;
        if(substr($key,0,7)=='L_NUMBER'){
            $itemnumber=$p_item;
        }
        if(substr($key,0,4)=='L_QTY'){
            $itemqty=$p_item;
        }
        $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
        (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
        VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID','$itemname','$itemnumber', $ItemTotalPrice,'$itemqty')");
    }       
}
```

This is the data array that i get from paypal

```html
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC%2d9AR564071F782043P
    [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 0
    [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionCompleted
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d08%2d25T08%3a44%3a23Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => b7dd304eefa54
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [EMAIL] => testcart2%40gmail%2ecom
    [PAYERID] => 84ZU7JDBQT4VL
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [FIRSTNAME] => Amin
    [LASTNAME] => black
    [COUNTRYCODE] => MY
    [SHIPTONAME] => Amin%20black
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => Level%2001%2c%20No%201%2c%20First%20Avenue%20Bandar%20Utama
    [SHIPTOCITY] => Petaling%20Jaya
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => Selangor
    [SHIPTOZIP] => 47800
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => MY
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => Malaysia
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
    [CURRENCYCODE] => MYR
    [AMT] => 1603%2e35
    [ITEMAMT] => 1603%2e35
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [HANDLINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [TAXAMT] => 0%2e00
    [INSURANCEAMT] => 0%2e00
    [SHIPDISCAMT] => 0%2e00
    [L_NAME0] => Android%20Phone%20FX1
    [L_NAME1] => Television%20DXT
    [L_NAME2] => External%20Hard%20Disk
    [L_NUMBER0] => PD1001
    [L_NUMBER1] => PD1002
    [L_NUMBER2] => PD1003
    [L_QTY0] => 5
    [L_QTY1] => 1
    [L_QTY2] => 1
    [L_TAXAMT0] => 0%2e00
    [L_TAXAMT1] => 0%2e00
    [L_TAXAMT2] => 0%2e00
    [L_AMT0] => 200%2e50
    [L_AMT1] => 500%2e85
    [L_AMT2] => 100%2e00
    [L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => MYR
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 1603%2e35
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 1603%2e35
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT] => 0%2e00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 3JR08628US197043Y
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => false
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Amin%20black
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] =>   Level%2001%2c%20No%201%2c%20First%20Avenue%20Bandar%20Utama
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Petaling%20Jaya
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => Selangor
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 47800
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => MY
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => Malaysia
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS] => None
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Android%20Phone%20FX1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Television%20DXT
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2] => External%20Hard%20Disk
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => PD1001
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1] => PD1002
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER2] => PD1003
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 5
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0] => 0%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT1] => 0%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT2] => 0%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 200%2e50
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 500%2e85
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2] => 100%2e00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE1] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE2] => %20%20%200%2e00000
    [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID] => 3JR08628US197043Y
    [PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE] => 0
)
```

Comment: it appears that you are getting a key that starts with L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0, which means that the substr(0,5) = "L_PAYM" but you are looking for "L_NAME"

Comment: so i need to change from =='L_NAME' to L_PAYM? or?

Comment: by the way, if you have any other better methods feel free to share, right now the thing that i want to save is the quantity name and code.

Comment: I would probably go for  substr(0, -1) == "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME", since "L_PAYM" would match all the parameters (_QTY, _AMT, etc)

Comment: but the code still won't work as you expect. Do you get the number and qty from paypal too? i think you are missing some logic. can you post a var_dump of the array $httpParsedResponseAr ?

Comment: can i make a 2nd query to update the data in the same page by using the id? perhaps i can just take the data from my own cart. can it be done so? if it can be done like that, after succes in running the query i just make if statement to update the data.

Comment: or i need to split table between the item data and buyer data?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below and see if that helps you out. the problem with the code you posted is that you will not get all the values in the insert statement at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this code - this loops through the array, finds the payment numbers and create an insert query for each.

```
<?php
$httpParsedResponseAr = array("TOKEN" => "EC%2d9AR564071F782043P",
    "BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS" => "0",
    "CHECKOUTSTATUS" => "PaymentActionCompleted",
    "TIMESTAMP" => "2015%2d08%2d25T08%3a44%3a23Z",
    "CORRELATIONID" => "b7dd304eefa54",
    "ACK" => "Success",
    "VERSION" => "109%2e0",
    "BUILD" => "000000",
    "EMAIL" => "testcart2%40gmail%2ecom",
    "PAYERID" => "84ZU7JDBQT4VL",
    "PAYERSTATUS" => "verified",
    "FIRSTNAME" => "Amin",
    "LASTNAME" => "black",
    "COUNTRYCODE" => "MY",
    "SHIPTONAME" => "Amin%20black",
    "SHIPTOSTREET" => "Level%2001%2c%20No%201%2c%20First%20Avenue%20Bandar%20Utama",
    "SHIPTOCITY" => "Petaling%20Jaya",
    "SHIPTOSTATE" => "Selangor",
    "SHIPTOZIP" => "47800",
    "SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE" => "MY",
    "SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME" => "Malaysia",
    "ADDRESSSTATUS" => "Unconfirmed",
    "CURRENCYCODE" => "MYR",
    "AMT" => "1603%2e35",
    "ITEMAMT" => "1603%2e35",
    "SHIPPINGAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "HANDLINGAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "TAXAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "INSURANCEAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "SHIPDISCAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "L_NAME0" => "Android%20Phone%20FX1",
    "L_NAME1" => "Television%20DXT",
    "L_NAME2" => "External%20Hard%20Disk",
    "L_NUMBER0" => "PD1001",
    "L_NUMBER1" => "PD1002",
    "L_NUMBER2" => "PD1003",
    "L_QTY0" => "5",
    "L_QTY1" => "1",
    "L_QTY2" => "1",
    "L_TAXAMT0" => "0%2e00",
    "L_TAXAMT1" => "0%2e00",
    "L_TAXAMT2" => "0%2e00",
    "L_AMT0" => "200%2e50",
    "L_AMT1" => "500%2e85",
    "L_AMT2" => "100%2e00",
    "L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" => "MYR",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" => "1603%2e35",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT" => "1603%2e35",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT" => "0%2e00",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID" => "3JR08628US197043Y",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED" => "false",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME" => "Amin%20black",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET" => "  Level%2001%2c%20No%201%2c%20First%20Avenue%20Bandar%20Utama",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY" => "Petaling%20Jaya",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE" => "Selangor",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP" => "47800",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE" => "MY",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME" => "Malaysia",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS" => "Unconfirmed",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS" => "None",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0" => "Android%20Phone%20FX1",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1" => "Television%20DXT",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2" => "External%20Hard%20Disk",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0" => "PD1001",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1" => "PD1002",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER2" => "PD1003",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0" => "5",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1" => "1",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2" => "1",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0" => "0%2e00",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT1" => "0%2e00",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT2" => "0%2e00",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0" => "200%2e50",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1" => "500%2e85",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2" => "100%2e00",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE1" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE2" => "%20%20%200%2e00000",
    "PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID" => "3JR08628US197043Y",
    "PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE" => "0");

foreach($httpParsedResponseAr as $key=>$p_item){
    $itemname='';
    $itemqty='';
    $itemnumber='';
    //identify name of item (ignoring number at end)
    if(substr($key,0, -1) == "L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME"){
        //same the name
        $itemname=$p_item;
        //save the number
        $itemnum = substr($key,-1, 1);
        //use number to get itemNum
        $itemnumber=$httpParsedResponseAr["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER".$itemnum];
        //use number to get Qty
        $itemqty=$httpParsedResponseAr["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY".$itemnum];
        //create insert
        //echo "'$itemname','$itemnumber','$itemqty'";
        $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
        (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
        VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID','$itemname','$itemnumber', $ItemTotalPrice,'$itemqty')"); 

        }      
    }
?>
```

Comment: its still not in the same row, the data split  row for each item i sent

Comment: Ah you want all the data on the same line??? That doesn't conform to normalization standards. how would you store a cart with 100+ items?

Comment: so better solution is to split table right? so but my understanding in database is really low, if u now how to split table and make the transaction id as the id of the item table, please guide me.

Comment: have one table containing the *order* information, and another with *order_details*, with a line for each item, with a foreign key to the order table, then you can write a select to retrieve the order from that.

Comment: so for your pasted example, you would get one line in order, and three lines in order_details

Comment: so i need to make 2 query? after finish insert data in order table, how to start a new query with a foreign key that link both table data to match for 1 order? or i need to create table relation? as i have mention above, im newb in sql.

Comment: btw, for the code that u have given me before, i get undefined index for L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY and L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER

Comment: $itemnum == substr($key,-1, 1);
 is wrong then. I'm not at my desk right now,  will look later

Comment: I have updated my code- i had used == should have been =. it works now

Comment: nice, tq, now all i need is to split table between order and order detail.